# Crystal Reports dont work in IIS

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, report

I have an app w C# & MySQL using Crystal Reports. In my development environment, the app works using. But when I published, the app shows me this error:

```
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.InternalException:
 No se pudo abrir la conexión. 
No se pudo abrir la conexión. 
 {E403D116-A2DD-482D-947B-8D4BFFE851A8}.rpt
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
No se pudo abrir la conexión. 
No se pudo abrir la conexión. Reporte 
{E403D116-A2DD-482D-947B-8D4BFFE851A8}.rpt 
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions
, RequestContext pRequestContext) 
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.
ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext 
reqContext) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.
ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e) 
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.
EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.
Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.
Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.
Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse
(ExportOptions options, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.
Engine.ReportDocument.
ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType formatType, HttpResponse response, 
Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName)
```

I installed in the server this:

[image: software]

I configured this in the server:

[image: ODBC]

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Ivo

Comment: have you installed the CRV on the server you are using??

Comment: I installed those in the server. I attached in the question.

Comment: I also reinstalled the CRforVS_redist. I read this site: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 I downloaded that software in http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_12.zip

But it didnt work, I mean the app dont show that error.. But I have a new one..

This:

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices
.COMException (0x80004005):
 The system cannot find the 
path specified. at CrystalDecisions.
ReportAppServer.
Controllers.ReportSourceClass.
Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, 
RequestContext pRequestContext) at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.
EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream
(ExportRequestContext reqContext) at
 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.
FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
 reqContext) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions